# NEST Protect device access fhem

Tags: google-oauth, device

Wie kann ein NEST Protect im Google Device Manager angegelegt werden?
Dann soll ein Zugriff aus FHEM über die Google API erfolgen.
Die API von Nest ist seit 2020 offline!

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is English only site. Please take [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to catch up basic stuff :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not written in English